# How to allow only one find per document searched on Lucene

Tags: lucene, fragment, lucene-highlighter

I only want my Lucene search to give the highest scoring highlighted fragment per document.  So say I have 5 documents with the word "performance" on each one three times, I still only want 5 results to be printed and highlighted to the results page.  How can I go about doing that?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get only one fragment per document returned from the search by calling [`getBestFragment`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_5_0/api/contrib-highlighter/org/apache/lucene/search/highlight/Highlighter.html#getBestFragment%28org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), rather than `getBestFragments`.

If your call to search is returning the same documents more than once, you very likely have more than one copy of the same document in your index.  Make sure that if you intend to create a new index, you open your `IndexWriter` with it's `OpenMode` set to: [`IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode.CREATE`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode.html#CREATE).